# Angular with Jasmine error: Controller required by directive can't be found

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have an application which has two directives, where one directive requires the other. I have replicated it to mirror the base of the application:

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', ['testApp.directiveA', 'testApp.directiveB']);

// Here goes your modules definition
module.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {
});

angular.module('testApp.directiveA', ['testApp.directiveB'])

.directive('directiveA', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
    require: '^directiveB',
        template: '<div><h1>DirectiveA</h1></div>',
    scope: {
      value: "@"
    },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, directiveBCtrl) {
            scope.testFunction = function() {
                return directiveBCtrl.exampleFunction();
            };

            scope.value = scope.testFunction();
        }
    }
});

angular.module('testApp.directiveB', [])

.directive('directiveB', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div><h1>DirectiveB</h1></div>',
    scope: {
      value: "@"
    },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.exampleFunction = function() {
                return true;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to write a test using Jasmine to test different functions in directiveA:

```
describe('Test directive with require', function () {

    var $scope, elem, scope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("testApp.directiveA", "testApp.directiveB"));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {

        elem = angular.element('<directive-a value="aValue"></directive-a>');

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $compile(elem)($scope);

        $scope.$digest();

        scope = elem.isolateScope();

    }));

    it('Should test a function on directiveA', function() {

        var result = scope.testFunction();
        expect(result).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Controller 'directiveB', required by directive 'directiveA', can't be found!
```

I have setup A Plnkr which reproduces the error. I cannot seem to figure out how I can inject one directive, or rather its controller, into the other directive. Any help is greatly appreciate.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pKDNkiO1ZHxE6qQKXXF5?p=preview

Comment: Did you try to create `directive-b` in your test like this: `elem = angular.element('<directive-b><directive-a value="aValue"></directive-a></directive-b>');` ?

Comment: This does get rid of the error that I was having, but I cannot (directly) access the scope of directive-a. The must be a way to inject directive-b into directive-a?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated jasmine `beforeEach` code (or [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fxRxv6rpgkzpsJnCBBwL?p=preview)):

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    elem = angular.element('<directive-b><directive-a value="aValue"></directive-a></directive-b>');
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile(elem)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
    scope = elem.children(':first').isolateScope();
}));
```

And updated directiveB code:

```
directive('directiveB', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        //template: '<div><h1>DirectiveB</h1></div>',
        scope: {
            value: "@"
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.exampleFunction = function() {
                return true;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Takeaway:

1. Wrap your directive into required directive and get its scope with `elem.children(':first').isolateScope()`
2. Required directive shouldn't have a template, otherwise it will override your directive indside
3. Use `this` to create controller methods instead of `$scope`

**UPD:**

You can use transclude if your parent directive needs to have a template. Here is a [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJpZtt7bWxfvhJTIc8AU?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for your effort. My directiveB does have a template which I cannot remove. I understand that it is possible to get the child's scope from a parents. And to solve the template issue I can probably make the directive transcluded. But I can't imagine it isn't possible to test the directive as is. It must be possible to inject the directiveB into directiveA somehow?

Comment: You right, just try to transclude it and get `directive-a` scope with `elem.find('directive-a').isolateScope()`

Comment: @DaanvanHulst, added `transclude` example to the answer

Comment: Hopefully this is helpful for someone else, but I would still like to know how I can test the directiveA as is. I will see if I can dive into the workings of 'require' to see how Angular includes a directive.

Comment: What do you mean as is? Like mocking directiveB?

Comment: You might want to look into [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19951141/1224211)