# How do I properly initialize/mock and unit test input data in a directive's externally-defined controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a custom directive that uses an external controller and template.  The user passes in some initial data to the directive, which is used inside the controller.

When I'm unit testing myController, **this.inputData** is initially undefined.  How do I initialize or mock **this.inputData** in my unit test so that I can properly test that **myCustomFilter** was called with a defined value in its first parameter?

**CustomDirective:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirectve', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                inputData: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'templates/my-directive-template.html',
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs: 'main',
            controller: 'myMainCtrl',
            link: function () { }
        };
    });
```

**DirectiveController:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('myMainCtrl', function (myCustomFilter) {
        this.filteredData = myCustomFilter(this.inputData, true);
    });
```

**my-directive-template:**

```
<span>{{ main.filteredData.length }}</span>
```

**Using MyDirective:**

```
<my-directive inputData="myInputData"></my-directive>
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227036/testing-directives-that-require-controllers ?

Comment: @Nicolas I tried some things referenced in that question, but nothing seemed to help.  In defining my directive's controller externally, I'm hoping to be able to unit test the controller on its own.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to set a value on this.inputData before my controller is initialized.