# How do I test an Angular directive that requires another controller in Angular 1.3.14?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm attempting to write Jasmine tests for a directive that requires a parent directive to be present.  I found this question:
[Testing directives that require controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227036/testing-directives-that-require-controllers), however, this is a bit dated (Angular 1.1.5 I believe), and the plunkr doesn't appear to work with new versions of Jasmine (2.2.1) and Angular (1.3.14).  I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous>         (http://run.plnkr.co/AHQtPtvSezB4DsnJ/appSpec.js:18:33)
```

Here's the code:
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.add = function(x, y) {
        return x + y;
      }
    }
  };
});

app.directive('bar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^foo',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, foo) {
      scope.callFoo = function(x, y) {
        scope.sum = foo.add(x, y);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

And the test:

```
describe('Testing directives', function() {
  var $scope, $compile, element;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('plunker');

    inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $compile = _$compile_;
    });
  });

  it('ensures callFoo does whatever it is supposed to', function() {
    // Arrange
    var element = $compile('<foo><bar></bar></foo>')($scope);
    var fooController = element.controller('foo');
    var barScope = element.find('bar').scope();
    spyOn(fooController, 'add').andReturn(3);

    // Act
    barScope.callFoo(1, 2);

    // Assert
    expect(barScope.sum).toBe(3);
    expect(fooController.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
  });
});
```

Here's the working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bC5BY81x0hi576xwSdyo?p=preview

I'm aware this design may not be the best, however, I'm sort of stuck with it at the moment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer in the above mention SO question, method #3 worked great.  I apparently didn't read far enough.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951141/629545