# angularjs: Testing Controller-based Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, karma-jasmine

I have a Directive bind to a Controller via `ngController` as below:

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['myService',
    function(myService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            require: "^ngController",
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            link: {
                pre: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
                    scope.list = [];
                    myService.getData().then(function (response) {
                        scope.list = response.data;
                    });
                },
                post: function (scope) {
                    for (var rec = 0; rec < scope.list.length; rec++) {
                        if (scope.list[rec].key2 == 'd') {
                            // Do something here..
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Sample Controller is used (As this Directive is used in multiple places):

```
app.controller('testController', [
    function () {
        var testCtrl = this;
    }
]);
```

The test-case for the directive is:

```
describe('myDirective', function () {
    var element, scope, ctrl;
    beforeEach(angular.module('myModule'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $controller, $httpBackend) {
        mockBackEnd = $httpBackend;

        // Call to myService.getData()
        mockBackEnd.expectGET('/module/service/api').respond({
            values: [{key1: a, key2: b}, {key1: c, key2: d}]
        });

        element = angular.element('<div ng-controller="testController"><my-directive></my-directive></div>');
        ctrl = $controller('testController', {});
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        compile(element)(scope);
        mockBackEnd.flush();
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('Test for response', function () {
        expect(scope.list.length).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

I get an error saying: `PhantomJS 1.9.8 myDirective FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.list.length')`

Further inspection: On checking where `$digest()` happens, found that, in `post:` link function, `scope.list` object is appearing as `[]` where as it should be the returned value from service.

The directive, as is works fine in the module but throws issues in the test-cases.

What am I doing wrong here? Need some help in karma.

Comment: The first thing that is wrong is the `angular.module('myModule', [])` in both controller and directive. This is the initialization of the module and the last one executed overrides the first instance. You have to retrieve in one place the instance of the module. Second, in the test you have `<div ng-controller=testController>`, so you miss the quotes around the controller name. try these changes and see what is the result (probably there will be other errors in console too).

Comment: @DianaR Thank you for the pointers. Edited the code. This is a glimpse of the actual code used and hence, slipped over with your requested changes.

Comment: You are welcome. Ok. So is the test passing now?

Comment: No. It isn't. The error is the same.

Comment: Ok. Lets take a look at your controller definition. It doesn't look as a proper controller moreover, you are missing the scope injected in it. Fix this and we'll see what is next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it using some help [from the community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227036/testing-directives-that-require-controllers).

The fact is, as per comments/answers here, I was doing the testing incorrectly. The actual test-case setup should have been.

```
describe('myDirective', function () {
   var element, scope, ctrl, directiveScope;
   beforeEach(angular.module('myModule'));
   beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $controller, $httpBackend) {
      mockBackEnd = $httpBackend;

      // Call to myService.getData()
      mockBackEnd.expectGET('/module/service/api').respond({
        values: [{key1: a, key2: b}, {key1: c, key2: d}]
      });

      ctrl = $controller('testController', {});
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      element = $compile(angular.element('<div ng-controller="testController"><my-directive></my-directive></div>'))(scope);
      directiveScope = element.find('my-directive').scope();
      scope.$digest();
      mockBackEnd.flush();
}));

it('Test for response', function () {
    expect(directiveScope.list.length).toBe(2);
});
```

I was fiddling with the parent scope here, the directive's scope is not accessible from outside. Used `element.find().scope()` to get that scope first and use it to convenience.

After I modified to this new code, `pre-link` and `post-link` functions are executing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry @curlyreggie, when I look at your code, I can't really understand why it is so complex ?

Why don't you pass your data as array or JSON object to directive scope?

why you are using directive with ng-controller?

Anyway, to add some AngularJS functions to your directive in tests, use angular.element().

```
var compile = $compile; // is missing in your code
scope = $rootScope.$new();

var element = angular.element('<my-directive ng-controller="testController">Add all parameters, as you usually do in your html, if missing anything</my-directive>');
compile(element)(scope);
scope.$digest();

// Get the isolate scope for the directive
var isolatedScope = element.isolateScope();
console.log("isolatedScope", isolatedScope);
```

And 'mockBackEnd' usually I inject like that:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $controller, $injector) {
   mockBackEnd = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
   .....
}
```

not sure if that works, but at least I tried to help you :)

Comment: Sorry for that `$compile` mistake. It is actually an `angular.element()`. Edited the same. Also, this directive serves as a template API for all controllers that it can bound to. Data is served to controller for usage.

Comment: In fact, using `isolatedScope()` also gives the same `undefined` error.

Comment: what if you remove "scope: true," from directive, as you are using shared controller from parent

Comment: Sorry. that doesn't help. Issue persists.