# Angular 1.5 unit test controller that requires parent component's controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-components

I'm trying to unit test a (child) controller of an AngularJS 1.5 (with Webpack) component that requires a parent component and a controller from another module.

Child controller structure:

```
function ChildController () {
  var vm = this;

  vm.searchText = '';

  vm.submit = function() {
    var data = {};
    data['srch'] = vm.searchText;
    vm.parentCtrl.submitTextSearch(data);
  };
}

module.exports = ChildController;
```

Child component:

```
var template = require('./child.html');
var controller = require('./child.controller');

var childComponent = {
  require: {
    parentCtrl: '^parent'
  },
  template: template,
  controller: controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
};

module.exports = childComponent;
```

So what I would like to do is to mock out the parentCtrl that's required in the childController's submit()-function. I've been unable to find how to actually do this. I've found some similar child-parent directive solutions and tried those, e.g. injecting the parent controller through fake HTML-element as described in [this child-parent directive example](https://demisx.github.io/angularjs/unit-testing/2014/10/28/unit-testing-angular-child-directive-that-requires-parent.html) and basically the same [stackoverflow solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227036/testing-directives-that-require-controllers) with no results. My problems differ at least in the fact that the child and parent controller are in different modules. And I suppose scope-tricks are not that much Angular 1.5-style?

The skeleton of my Jasmine test without my failed mock attempts:

```
describe('child component', function() {
  describe('child controller', function() {
    var controller;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('child'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$componentController_) {
      controller = _$componentController_('child');
    }))
    it('should work', function() {
      controller.searchText = "test";
      controller.submit();
    })
  })
})
```

That results in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'submitTextSearch' of undefined`. What exactly should I do to mock the parent controller out? With my limited experience in Angular, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you're add `parentCtrl` as dependency of your component so in order to test it you have to mock parent component as well and assign it to controller. So you'd need to do something like:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$componentController_) {
  controller = _$componentController_('child');
  parentCtrl = _$componentController_('parent');
  controller.parentCtrl = parentCtrl;
}))
```

Comment: I've tried this but doesn't work for me. Still getting "Controller '<parent>', required by directive '<child>', can't be found!".

Comment: Are you sure about your karma configuration ? Maybe some files are not being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

> **1.** Solution

In your test instantiate the parent controller with a new scope:

```
mainScope = $rootScope.$new();
$controller('ParentController', {$scope: mainScope});
```

and in your child controller, instantiate a new scope using the previously instantiated scope:

```
childScope = mainScope.$new();
$controller('ChildController', {$scope: childScope});
```

Example from the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

```
describe('state', function() {

  var mainScope, childScope, grandChildScope;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      mainScope = $rootScope.$new();
      $controller('MainController', {$scope: mainScope});
      childScope = mainScope.$new();
      $controller('ChildController', {$scope: childScope});
      grandChildScope = childScope.$new();
      $controller('GrandChildController', {$scope: grandChildScope});
  }));

  it('should work', function() {
      grandChildScope.searchText = "test";
      grandChildScope.submit();
  });
});
```

> **2.** Solution

Child controller structure:

```
function ChildController () {
  var vm = this;

  vm.searchText = '';

  vm.submit = function() {
    var data = {};
    data['srch'] = vm.searchText;
    vm.parentCtrl.submitTextSearch(data);
  };
}

module.exports = ChildController;
```

Child component:

```
var template = require('./child.html');
var controller = require('./child.controller');

    var childComponent = {
      bindings: {
         searchText: 'test'
      },
      template: template,
      controller: controller,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    };

module.exports = childComponent;

var ChildController = $componentController('childComponent', null, {...});
ChildController.$onInit();
expect(ChildController.searchText).to.equal('test');
expect(ChildController.submit()).to.equal('*expected result value should come here*');
```

> **REFRENCES :**

[AngularJS documentation - Testing Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

[AngularJS documentation - $componentController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$componentController)

[Unit Testing Angular Components with $componentController](http://www.codelord.net/2017/01/09/unit-testing-angular-components-with-%24componentcontroller/)

Answer (score 1):

Using the below code will get it initialized and please check the working Jasmine unit test [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NPdcbbte8vp82xs3joi7?p=preview)

```
var ctrP = $componentController('parentComp');
var ctrl = $componentController('childComp', {}, {
  parentCtrl: ctrP
});
```

And your test case should be as shown below:

```
'use strict';

describe('component: heroDetail', function() {
  var $componentController, $compile, $rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$componentController_) {
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
  }));

  it('should expose a `hero` object', function() {
    var ctrP = $componentController('parentComp');
    console.log(ctrP);
    var ctrl = $componentController('childComp', {}, {
      parentCtrl: ctrP
    });
    console.log(ctrl);
    ctrl.submit('some data');
    expect(ctrl.parentCtrl.searchText).toEqual('some data');

  });
});
```